# Command history in Vmd text mode

Tags: vmd

How can I activate command history or autocomplete in VMD text mode (vmd shell)

```
vmd >
```

I use it in Linux Ubuntu, when I use arrow keys it prints characters like `^[[A`.

Answer (score 3):

The `rlwrap` package automatically provides this functionality to `vmd`'s text mode:

```
$ sudo apt install rlwrap
```